# Separating/protecting sensitive business layer logic from client side script in single page app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, single-page-application

We've developed some environmental impact calculations and spent a lot of money having them checked and approved by qualified 3rd parties. I'm currently moving our website from traditional asp.net client/server code to a single page application.

Obviously if I was to do the calculations on the client side in script then even if I obfuscated the code with non-semantic variable names, our competitors would be able to reverse-engineer the code fairly easily.

Being somewhat new to all this, my idea is to have the calculations done in asp.net server code called by the same web api that I use for database interactions so I can make async calls which update the relevant parts of the page (via knockout) when the calculation is finished.

Is this the standard/best way to do this or am I completely missing a better way?

Comment: That is about the only way you can protect your data/calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Service Oriented approach could be a solution for you. 
You can use WCF or Web services for all your calculations (or other services) then using ajax call, bring the result back to the client 
So you actually create WCF services and then consume it using client script

Here is a step by step approach to consume a webservice using javascript
http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/03/06/step-by-step-how-to-use-web-services-in-asp-net-ajax.aspx

Comment: Thanks Kiarash. Any examples online you can point me to that explain this approach a bit more so I can consider it please?